# How to allow users to @ mention your github app

Tags: github, github-api, github-app

I have a github app and I'd like for users to give it commands by commenting on PRs.

Since users comment on PRs for many reasons I'd like to start my command with an @ mention to my github app.

This is a pattern dependabot uses with commands starting with `@dependabot` such as `@dependabot ignore`

When I try to @ mention my app in a PR it doesn't show me this option as it does for dependabot.

How do I enable this for my app?

Comment: A similar question was opened [on GitHub](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/54188). Linking that here in case that gets an answer first.